# MVC jquery ajax call with input parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing a problem when calling an action on a controller with an argument

In the controller i have following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateData(string month)
{
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Hello world" });
}
```

The ajax call in the view looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateData")',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    data: {  },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

this works well, but when i want to pass the argument like

```
data: {month:'may'}
```

i get an error, the action is never called.  I just don't see it.

**EDIT :**

Ok, i just had to pass the json as a string:

```
data: "{month:'may'}"
```

I think i need more sleep :-)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: What you need to do is remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and use `data: {month:'may'} `

Comment: It works, thanks!  And i'll use the asp.net-mvc tag next time ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **just remove content type** and also **better** if you **pass controller name in URL**:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateData","YourControllerName")',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",            
        cache: false,
        data: {month:'may'} ,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
});
```